# last inserted id problem, mysqli_insert_id($link), giving me only 0

Tags: php, mysqli

i did read documentation,  `$la=Mysqli_insert_id($db);` is always 0 `$db= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_site");` also i do have in my db "AUTO INCREMENT" here is (screenshot of db structure, see below), with `mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_site")` i do insert data into db, so its working correctly,
here is the code that inserts data

```
       $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO news (title,content,date,thumbnail) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
       $sql->bind_param("ssss", $title, $content, $date, $thumbnail");
       $sql->execute();
       $sql->close();
       $db->close();
```

what could be problem?? if needed i will provide all source code, but its very messy and big

[image]

Comment: At what point do you call `Mysqli_insert_id()` - think you would need to call it before calling the various `close()` methods.

Comment: If that does not solve the problem provide all source code (after clean up....)

Comment: yes man, i though that problem was where i was callin it too, so i tryed to put `Mysqli_insert_id()` add and delete everywhere, didn't work

Comment: also somehow i had 2 autoincrements on 2 several tables on that db, so i complitely deleted second table still didn't work

Comment: hey man i double checked and u are right `Mysqli_insert_id($link)` needs to be after  `execute()` and before `close()`;  i may be wrong but if its above execute it stops working, why??? all i am asking is last id, why does this need to be after inserting on db?

Comment: @Varomy It has to be after the `INSERT` query takes place because the id was generated with the `INSERT` query. It can't be before, the query wasn't executed yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?php
   $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO news (title,content,date,thumbnail) VALUES (?, ?, 
   ?, ?)");
   $sql->bind_param("ssss", $title, $content, $date, $thumbnail");
   $sql->execute();
   $sql->close();
   $db->close();
      ?>
```

`Mysqli_insert_id($link);`  need to be called after `execute()` and before `close();`

Comment: Your example code still does not call `mysqli_insert_id`